# Rails Asset Paths are different on different machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am developing a rals 3.2.8 application. I started it on my Mac and copied it to a linux machine. The linux machine gives an error line the following.

```
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
```

I checked Rails.application.config.assets.paths and realized that it's different on my Mac and the Linux. Did I miss something?

Thanks.

===========UPDATE============

I found a weird thing. Even if my development env and design env (which I copied from config/environments/development.rb) are identical, Rails.application.config.assets.paths are different.

Here's a capture from my console.

```
[ssk-MBP]~/dev/test$ r c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.8.7 :001 > Rails.application.config.assets.paths
 => ["/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/app/assets/images", "/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@dentisusa/gems/jquery-rails-2.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@dentisusa/gems/underscore-rails-1.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@dentisusa/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.1.0.0/vendor/assets/images", "/Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@dentisusa/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.1.0.0/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@dentisusa/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.1.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@dentisusa/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts", #<Pathname:/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/jquery-ui-rails-2.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets>] 
1.8.7 :002 > exit
[ssk-MBP]~/dev/test$ r c design
Loading design environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.8.7 :001 > Rails.application.config.assets.paths
 => ["/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/app/assets/images", "/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@dentisusa/gems/jquery-rails-2.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts", #<Pathname:/Users/ssk/dev/dentisusa/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/jquery-ui-rails-2.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets>] 
1.8.7 :002 >
```

What did I do wrong?

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix it.

config/application.rb

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test design)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

I added 'design' to it.

It took me almost a whole day.

Sam

Comment: Good to know, thanks for posting back the answer. I'm sure I'll run in to this one sooner or later ;) The asset pipeline is a little too magical for my taste if I'm honest.

Answer (score 1):

Since asset paths are defined by the application I can't imagine why the machine's operating system should have any effect on application configuration.

Apologies for the obvious question but you are using the same environment on both machines? (i.e. not production on one and development on the other?) That's the only possibility that springs to mind. You could try grep'ing for the different paths in your config directory as well. (e.g. grep strange_asset_path -r config)

Comment: Your answer gives me some confidence. Actually the env is not the same. I made an env by copying config/environments/development.rb to config/environments/design.rb. So it should be the same. I'll keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: One difference is that the Mac rails is using rvm and the Linux rails is not.

Comment: rvm in itself shouldn't make any difference, as long as your gem versions are the same. Those are the only two causes I can think of, Rails' gem versions or the environment definitions in config/ (or I suppose a setting config/application.rb would be possible.) One last thought, you could do a `grep -r "config.assets.paths" .` in your app root. That should definitively show all possible places where the configuration might be changed.

Comment: Strangely, if I change the RAILS_ENV to production, it works on Linux. Only design mode (same as development) causes trouble. Any idea? I'll check with rubygems and others you mentioned. Thanks.